# How to pronounce "Herbrand" in French?

Tags: prononciation, noms-propres

In mathematical logic, we have Herbrand theorem and Herbrand normal form which are named after [Jacques Herbrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Herbrand).

Now I need to know the exact pronunciation of "Herbrand" (of which I only know the overall pronunciation) to translate it into Chinese from the sound.

So is there any native French to know how to pronounce "Herbrand"? If so, please use the [International Phonetic Alphabet for French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/French) to show how to pronounce "Herbrand".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a native French speaker, so I'll let a native speaker answer. But given the spelling, there's essentially only one way to pronounce it, which is the way it's pronounced on [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/search/Herbrand/): /ɛʁbʁɑ̃/.

Comment: @PeterShor Ah, you focus on names in other languages too ...

Comment: Yes, and I also know a reasonable amount of French.

Comment: @PeterShor You may be also interested in [the pronunciation for Dedekind here](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/72257/54540).

Comment: The premise of this question is very strange. For sure books have been written in Chinese which contain the name of Jacques Herbrand, therefore you should follow the existing consensus rather than trying to create your own transliteration from scratch. For example, Wikipedia suggests 雅克 埃尔布朗.

Comment: @Picrow In China, there are possibly several translations for a name, and so it's necessary to know its exact sound to determine which one is the most close. Also, in China many people including some scholars read "Herbrand" wrong. For inconvenient communications earlier and loss of internet sources, some translators determine some sounds of French names by guess. So many transliterations are not exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In French, a leading *H* is never pronounced and a trailing *D* is not pronounced when following a consonant, so, as @PeterShor already commented, there is only one way to pronounce it: /ɛʁbʁɑ̃/

You can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glEXCS1H7Pc&t=43s) on YouTube.

Comment: You can use my nickname and pronounce it the way you want :-) My own pronunciation is /ʒi.ɛl.ljagʁ/ something like "jee ell lee-a-gher".